# IO::Socket::SSL fails with IIS 8.5

Tags: perl, ssl, iis, cgi

Following script runs successfully when run with Perl CLI ( Windows). But when run through IIS 8.5, it fails.

```
use IO::Socket::SSL;

print <<EOP;
Content-type: text/html

<html><body>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
EOP

print "</body></html>\n";
```

Error message is

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server.

When "use IO::Socket::SSL" line is deleted, it is successfully executed.
With "use IO::Socket", it is too successfully executed.

Is there something wrong with my IIS / CGI configuration?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you need `use IO::Socket::SSL` in your server-side script? Or even `use IO::Socket` for that matter?

Comment: Where did you install the IO::Socket::SSL library? It's possible that the directory you installed it into is not in the default library search path that processes inherit from IIS.

Comment: Is there anything relevant in your web server's log files?

Comment: IO::Socket::SSL is installed in <perl distribution>/vendor/lib directory. No problem when using IO::Socket ( installed in same directory ) so I don't think it comes from library search path. I got following error message on my browser:

Comment: The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are "Can't load 'D:/strawberry-perl-5.26.1.1-64bit-portable/perl/site/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.xs.dll' for module Net::SSLeay: load_file:The specified module could not be found at D:/strawberry-perl-5.26.1.1-64bit-portable/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193. "

D:/strawberry-perl-5.26.1.1-64bit-portable/perl/site/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.xs.dll

Answer (score 0):

I added directory containing libcrypto-1_1-x64__.dll file into system PATH and rebooted the machine. It solved my issue.